# xyパッケージを使うと警告がでてしまう

Tags: latex

xyパッケージを使ってuplatexでビルドすると以下のような警告がでます。

> The produced DVI file is NOT PORTABLE. Convert it with
> dvipdfm(x) to the PDF format but do not expect the DVI file itself to be
> displayed correctly.

実行したソースファイルは以下の通りです。

```
\documentclass[uplatex, dvipdfmx]{jsarticle}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
  \xymatrix{
            X \ar[r]^f & Y \ar[r]^g & Z   
        }
\end{document}
```

\documentclass{article}にすると警告は出ないので、xyと日本語環境の何かの相性が悪いようです。
PDFは期待通りに出力されますし、エラーではないので無視し続けても構わないのですが、可能なら警告が出ないようにしたいです。どうするのが良いでしょうか？

Comment: 原因については回答にある通りです。対症療法として、プリアンブルに
`\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{xypdf}{The produced DVI file is NOT PORTABLE}`と入れれば警告は出なくなりました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

エンジンは uplatex を使ってそのあと dvipdfmx を使っていると想定します。警告の内容は「DVI がドライバ依存で dvipdfmx 専用になっているので注意せよ」ということですが，結論としては「気にしなくて良い」と思います。警告を消す手段はないので，諦める・あるいは・xy パッケージ著者に警告を消す手段を要求する（直接メール）等になります。

- uplatex + dvipdfmx という組み合わせを使う限り，問題は起きません。
- もしも途中の DVI を dviout (Windows) あるいは xdvi (Unix) などのビューアで見ようとすると，あるいは dvips で PostScript に変換しようとすると，不都合が起きるでしょう。しかし，dvipdfmx で PDF にしてしまえば関係ありません。

昔は DVI といえば DeVice-Independent すなわちドライバ非依存でしたが，下記の理由により最近は形骸化してしまっています：というのも，ユーザの皆さんが各自で決めた一定の手順（今回ならば uplatex + dvipdfmx）で TeX → PDF に変換することが多くなったためです。

---

「xyと日本語環境の何かの相性が悪い」というよりは「documentclass に dvipdfmx オプションをつけると xy パッケージが警告を出す」ということのようです。例えば

```
\documentclass{article}
```

では警告が出ず

```
\documentclass[dvipdfmx]{article}
```

では警告が出ます。逆に

```
\documentclass[uplatex]{jsarticle}
```

でも警告は出ません。

なぜ xy パッケージが警告を出すのかというと，xy パッケージが「dvipdfmx オプションを指定すると，dvipdfmx にしか解釈できない調整コード（中身の意味は難しいので割愛するが，例えば PDF に変換した時の線の太さなどの指示）を DVI ファイルに出力する」といういわゆるドライバ依存の挙動をするからです。graphicx, color, hyperref といった有名かつよく使われるパッケージが，ドライバ依存の代表格です。さらに言えば，今の時代（2020年以降）は「何もパッケージを読み込まない普通の LaTeX」すらドライバ依存性があります。そんな 2020 年代に xy パッケージ（最終更新は 2013 年なので割と古い）だけが警告を出すのはうるさく見えるかもしれませんが，気にしないのが得策でしょう。

参考：[Online.tex 2020](https://connpass.com/event/188075/) 講演資料[「最近の LaTeX は○○」](https://aminophen.github.io/slide/hytexonline20.pdf)

Comment: 勉強になりました。ドライバはオプションで指定すべきですし、指定しないと斜め線がガタガタするので、我慢します。